# Function call is returning MySQL Syntax Error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

MySQL keeps returning an error 1064 whenever i call a function to query my database, yet i cant seem to find my syntax error.

The error message is

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10,10' at line 1' in C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\UniServerZ\\www\\test\\User\\pdofunctions.inc:148\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\UniServerZ\\www\\test\\User\\pdofunctions.inc(148): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\UniServerZ\\www\\test\\User\\search.php(102): GetItemSubCategory(Object(PDO), 0, 0, 'Computers', 'Laptops')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\UniServerZ\\www\\test\\User\\pdofunctions.inc on line 148, referer: http://localhost/test/User/home.php
```

i realist that the part where it states

near '-10,10' at line 1' .....

is probably important but i cant seem to figure out the error.

My Function:

```
    function GetItemSubCategory($connection,$num,$page,$category,$subcategory)
{
    //Results per page
        $pagerows=10;
        //Tells us the last page number
        $last=ceil($num/$pagerows);
        // This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $page
        $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($page - 1) * $pagerows .',' .$pagerows;

        //Grabbing one page worth of results due to the use of $limit, results are ordered by BusinessName in descending order.
        $getpageresult=$connection->prepare("SELECT `ItemID`,`ItemName`,`ItemDesc`,`ItemPrice`,`ItemDP`,`EditDate`,`ItemCategory`,`ItemSubCategory` FROM `Items` WHERE `ItemCategory` =:itemcat AND `ItemSubCategory`=:itemsubcat ORDER BY `EditDate` DESC $limit");
        $getpageresult->bindValue(":itemcat",$category);
        $getpageresult->bindValue(":itemsubcat",$subcategory);
        $getpageresult->execute();

        //Initialises the $result variable to display the results of the query
        $result = '';
        while($row = $getpageresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $itemid = $row["ItemID"];
            $itemname = $row["ItemName"];
            $itemdesc=$row["ItemDesc"];
            $itemprice=$row["ItemPrice"];
            $itemdp=$row["ItemDP"];
            $editdate=$row['EditDate'];
            $itemcategory=$row["ItemCategory"];
            $result .= "<div id='SearchResult' class='SearchResult' >
                            <div class='SearchResultTop'><span class='SearchResultName'><a href='#'>$itemname</a></span><span class='SearchResultPrice'>$ $itemprice</span></div>
                            <div class='SearchResultMid'><a href='#' class='SearchResultImg'><img height=130px width=130px src=\"$itemdp\" alt=\"$itemname\"></a><div class='SearchResultDesc'>$itemdesc</div></div>
                            <div class='SearchResultBtm'><span class='SearchResultEditDate'>$editdate</span></div>
                        </div>";
        }
        return $result;
}
```

My HTML(extract):

```
//Additional code above which sets up the view,cat and subcat variable
elseif($view =="items")
{
    //Grabs total number of items and assigns it to the $count variable
    $count=GetItemCountSubCategory($cxn,$cat,$subcat);
    //Sets number of results on a page
    $pagerows=10;
    //Tells us the last page number
    $last=ceil($count/$pagerows);
    //Checks if the $_GET variable is present and sets the page to 1 if it is not
    if(!isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $pagenum = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['page']);
    }
    // This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
    if ($pagenum < 1) 
    { 
        $pagenum = 1; 
    }
    else if ($pagenum > $last) 
    { 
        $pagenum = $last; 
    }
    $pagecounter = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";
    $result=GetItemSubCategory($cxn,$count,$pagenum,$cat,$subcat);
    $pagination=Pagination($cxn,$count,$pagenum,$view);

}
```

I know that since the error message points to the line containing execute(); the problem should probably lie with the SELECT statement.Google has suggested that i may be getting the error due to the usage of reserved keywords, but i'm not, nor am i inserting invalid data types.

I've been stuck on this for quite some time and would appreciate any input.Thanks!

Comment: can you echo the actual query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`limit` clause requires both arguments to be **non-negative**.  Thanks to @JoniSalmi for reminding to take a second look at your limit clause.

Excerpt from the [`Select Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).

So in order to use the limits as is you need to update your query to use parameterized limit:

```
//Results per page
$pagerows=10;
//Tells us the last page number
$last=ceil($num/$pagerows);

// This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $page
$limit = ($page - 1) * $pagerows;


$getpageresult=$connection->prepare("SELECT `ItemID`,`ItemName`,`ItemDesc`,`ItemPrice`,`ItemDP`,`EditDate`,`ItemCategory`,`ItemSubCategory` FROM `Items` WHERE `ItemCategory` =:itemcat AND `ItemSubCategory`=:itemsubcat ORDER BY `EditDate` DESC limit :limit, :offset");
$getpageresult->bindValue(":itemcat",$category);
$getpageresult->bindValue(":itemsubcat",$subcategory);
$getpageresult->bindValue(":limit", $limit);
$getpageresult->bindValue(":offset", $pagerows);
```

Answer (score 1):

Limit seems to get negative values for the first part at least what is your $page

```
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($page - 1) * $pagerows .',' .$pagerows;
```

Try this

**Change**

```
if ($pagenum < 1) 
{ 
    $pagenum = 1; 
}
else if ($pagenum > $last) 
{ 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}
```

**To**

```
if ($pagenum > $last) 
{ 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}
if ($pagenum < 1) 
{ 
    $pagenum = 1; 
}
```

It seems like $last is only thing that could override your `$pagenum=0` which would cause your problem.

Maybe this should be

```
//change
$last=ceil($count/$pagerows);
//to
$last=$count * $pagerows;
```

Comment: The page should be 1, as $_GET["page"] is not set when the function is called.

Comment: What is $count value and $last to be spesific ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [**ternary**](http://php.net/ternary) operator along with `isset()` to ensure that the page defaults to 1 if `$_GET['page']` is not set.(ie at first load of page)

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '1';
```

Explanation

if `$_GET['page']` is set `$page = $_GET['page']`

if `$_GET['page']` is NOT set `$page =1`